# Get Device Information (device_name,device_os,device_uuid,device_model,device_version) In BB10 Webworks SDK

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

Good day i am developing an application using BB10 Webworks and bbui.js

I have installed the

```
org.apache.cordova.device
```

I have also modified the initial index.html file to point to this cordova.js file that uses this plugin like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../platforms/blackberry10/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

I try to initialize the global "device" variable using this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var device_name,device_os,device_uuid,device_model,device_version;
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


  function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Dev name"+device.name);
   device_name=device.name;
```

The issue is that when the page loads...i get the following errors:

```
ripple.js:50 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:8472/Device/getDeviceInfo'.

 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

cordova.js:980 Channel not fired: onNativeReady

cordova.js:980 Channel not fired: onPluginsReady

cordova.js:980 Channel not fired: onCordovaReady

cordova.js:987 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

 cordova.js:980 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

How can i get the required device information in  BB10 webworks?

Comment: Try updating your script tag to this
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
Let me know if this works

Comment: I am pointing to the cordova.js file that exists in the plugin directory

Comment: Did you tried with the one i suggested ?

Comment: There is no cordova.js file in my www directory..thats why i include the full path to the href...doing what you suggested gives a "not found" error

Comment: how are you building your app ?

Comment: I am using blackberry10 webworks